# sum $\displaystyle \sum _{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+n-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, fractions

I have the following series:

$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+n-2}$$

I am not able to do the telescoping process in the above series. I converted it into the following partial fraction:
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)(n-1)}$$
But nothing seems to cancel (as usually happens) using the telescoping method. How can I solve the above series? Is there any other method to do the above problem?

Comment: That's not the partial fraction....

Comment: See also: [Find the sum of series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+n-2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1732188). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5En%7D%7Bn%5E2%2Bn-2%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the $n$th term of your sum in a form that telescopes can be avoid altogether by converting the problem to a double integral as follows.

Noting that
$$\frac{1}{n - 1} = \int_0^1 x^{n - 2} \, dx \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{1}{n + 2} = \int_0^1 y^{n + 1} \, dy,$$
the sum can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + n - 2} &= \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n - 1)(n + 2)}\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty (-1)^n x^{n - 2} y^{n + 1} \, dx dy \tag1\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y}{x^2} \sum_{n = 2}^\infty (-xy)^n \, dx dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y}{x^2} \cdot \frac{x^2 y^2}{1 + xy} \, dx dy \tag2\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^3}{1 + xy} \, dx dy\\
&= \int_0^1 y^2 \Big{[} \ln (1 + xy) \Big{]}_0^1 \, dy\\
&= \int_0^1 y^2 \ln (1 + y) \, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \ln (2) - \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{y^3}{1 + y} \, dy \tag3\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \ln (2) - \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \left (y^2 - y + 1 - \frac{1}{1 + y} \right ) \, dy \tag4\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \ln (2) - \frac{1}{3} \left [\frac{y^3}{3} - \frac{y^2}{2} + y - \ln (1 + y) \right ]_0^1\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \ln (2) - \frac{5}{18}.
\end{align*}

**Explanation**

1. Interchanging the summation with the double integration.
2. Summing the series which is geometric.
3. Integration by parts.
4. Partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Hello, omegadot. I liked the way you solved this sum problem. I am thinking whether this method of summing can be applied in other situations also.

Comment: Also, can you please give me more intuition as to why you have integrated the sum because the integral is sum under the hood. Aren't we doing things twice?. Can you please explain the intuition behind this?

Comment: Whenever I see linear factors in the denominator of a convergent sum and a numerator of either $1$ or $(-1)^n$ I immediately think of trying to write the $n$th term of the sum in terms of an integral. After interchanging the integral sign with the summation, summing the resultant series which is geometric can be readily done. One hopefully can then perform the remaining integration. I have recently done this for a number of examples which you can follow [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636301/how-does-one-prove-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1nn1n2-2-log-2-1/2636411#2636411).

Comment: I must say very good approach. Have you done research or something on this topic. I tried it in many other examples also, and it worked quite easy than other traditional methods.

Comment: It is just another tool to add to your toolbox. The only potential problem the method may throw up is integrals which are either tedious or difficult to find.

Comment: It means if integral can be calculated, then this method can work for most of the problems where denominator is a Linear factor and numerator is either $1$ or $(-1)^n$.

Comment: Yes. But remember the sum this can be done on must first converge (try the technique on $\sum_{n =1}^\infty 1/n$ as see what happens) and the number of linear factors appearing in the denominator should not be too many since as their number grows the number of integrations that need to be performed also grows and can become very tedious.

Comment: Yes, I will take care of the suggestions you provided.

Comment: And as an example of a sum that leads to a more difficult integral to find (unless you are familiar with special functions that is or other more advanced techniques for finding improper integrals) is $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/n^2$. See what you end up with if you let $1/n = \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \, dx$ and $1/n = \int_0^1 y^{n - 1} \, dy$.

Comment: If you don't mind, the following question has been unanswered for long. You can look at it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632555/checking-the-differentiability-of-the-two-variables-function

Answer (score 8):

You need to fully expand the partial fraction.

\begin{align}
(-1)^n \over (n+2)(n-1)
&= {((n+2) - (n-1)) \times (-1)^n \over 3\times (n+2)(n-1)} \\
&= {(n+2) \times (-1)^n \over 3\times (n+2)(n-1)} - {(n-1) \times (-1)^n \over 3\times (n+2)(n-1)} \\
&= {(-1)^n \over 3\times (n-1)} - {(-1)^n \over 3\times (n+2)} 
\end{align}

Now this can be handled using [Alternating Harmonic Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlternatingHarmonicSeries.html).

The final result, as [Mathematica calculated](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxCG4NDdaQ9dQMy5PQV9BIy/OSDtP10hTR6E6T0fBSEfBMy8tMy@zpLI29v9/AA), is $\frac {-5 + 12 \log 2} {18}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+n-2}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}+...\right)=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{2}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\frac{2}{3}\ln2-\frac{5}{18}.$$