# How does one prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)(n+2)} = 2 \log 2 -1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)(n+2)} = 2 \log 2 -1$$
Saw this result on wikipedia, but I can’t seem to find a proof of this anywhere.

I’m rather slow, so if you know the solution, I’d appreciate it if it were worked out, instead of merely hinted at.

Comment: Probably use partial decomposition...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum can be found using our [favourite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334870/how-to-find-sum-of-the-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-n2n1/2615666#2615666) alternative method of converting the sum to a double integral first.

Noting that
$$\frac{1}{n + 1} = \int_0^1 x^n \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{n + 2} = \int_0^1 y^{n + 1} \, dy,$$
the sum can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^n y^{n + 1} \, dx dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 y \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-xy)^n dx dy \tag1\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 y \cdot \frac{1}{1 + xy} \, dx dy \tag2\\
&= \int_0^1 \ln (1 + xy) \Big{|}_0^1 \, dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \ln (1 + y) \, dy\\
&= \Big{[}(1 + y) \ln (1 + y) - (1 + y) \Big{]}_0^1\\
&= 2 \ln (2) - 1,
\end{align*}
as required.

**Explanation**

(1) Interchanging the summation with the double integration.

(2) Summing the series which is geometric.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+2)}$$

and    [Alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) convergence to $\log 2$.

Comment: How do you type so fast

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @gimusi! That should have been obvious. xD

Comment: @YuriyS and I'm not the faster! :)

Comment: @LostInNumbers You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me offer a terrible 'proof' based on hypergeometric functions. Consider the series:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)(n+2)} $$

Let's check the ratio of subsequent general terms (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)):

$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{(n+2)(n+3)}x=\frac{(n+1)}{(n+3)}x=\frac{(n+1)(n+1)}{(n+3)}\frac{x}{n+1}$$

Which by definition makes the series proportional to the hypergeometric function:

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2} {_2 F_1} (1,1;3;x)$$

The factor before the function is $t_0=1/2$.

The general form of this function is (you can check with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric2F1%5B1,1,3,x%5D) for example, or you can use another definition of the function, such as the integral definition):

$${_2 F_1} (1,1;3;x)=2 \frac{x+(1-x) \log (1-x)}{x^2}$$

Substituting $x=-1$, we obtain:

$$f(-1)= \frac{1}{2} {_2 F_1} (1,1;3;-1)=2 \log 2-1$$

This 'proof' is just for fun, but getting to hypergeometric form can be a valid method for a lot of other series, because there's a lot of reduction formulas for hypergeometric functions, and programs such as Mathematica can easily reduce them.